# I want to add a variable for the results from the formula of one variable and the beginning of another variable

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

This is the file name in question `OD_Orders_2019-02-19.csv`

I am trying to create a bash script to read into files with yesterday's date on the file name while retaining the rest of the files name. I would like for `$y` to equal the name of the file with a formula output with the exact date in the middle. So far this is what I have:

To get yesterday's date in the correct format, I made x:

```
x="date -d yesterday +%Y-%m-%d"

y="OD_Orders_$x.csv"
```

This issue with this is that the results when I do a echo `$y` gives me this:
`OD_Orders_date -d yesterday +%Y-%m-%d.csv`

I need to show the value of `$x` when `echo $y` correctly without it showing the formula. I need `$y` to input the filename with yesterday's date in the correct format because I want to use it more later on within this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) `$( ... )` to substitute the output of the command instead of the command itself:

```
x="$(date -d yesterday +%Y-%m-%d)"
y="OD_Orders_${x}.csv"
```

---

Which of course could be simplified to:

```
y="OD_Orders_$(date -d yesterday +%Y-%m-%d).csv"
```

Comment: You Sir are the MAN! Thank you very much! I was up all night for hours and couldn't solve this.